# sails js assign rollback from .create() to variable

Tags: function, variables, sails.js, waterline, assign

I know that it is trivial to many, but not for me because I am new to this. I need to assign the rollback function from create function to one variable I try:

```
var obj_transaction = Transaction.create({ amount: 200 }).exec(function(err, transaction){
                                    return transaction;//if print transaction here returns json of new transaction
                                });
res.json(obj_transaction);//print undefined
return;
```

But this does not work, when I print `obj_transaction` it returns undefined, I need `obj_transaction` with info of new created transaction.

Answer (score 0):

You can,t assign like this, because as create request make async call, the code of execution transfer to next line res.json before the callback function is called. 
So res.json will be called before new data assign to variable. That is why, it gives u undefined.